# regex split by block filter by content

Tags: regex

I want to remove every bloc starting by X, finishing by Y and containing value Z

http://regex101.com/r/jS7eA5

Text:

```
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 1234
BOOL:TRUE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 4568
BOOL:TRUE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 715310
BOOL:FALSE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 12489453
BOOL:TRUE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 41543
BOOL:FALSE
END
```

Result :

```
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 1234
BOOL:TRUE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 4568
BOOL:TRUE
END
BEGIN
DESCRIPTION: 12489453
BOOL:TRUE
END
```

Here, we want to remove every bloc starting by "BEGIN", ENDING BY "END", WITH "BOOL:FALSE" INSIDE.
another point of view : I want to keep every bloc  starting by "BEGIN", ENDING BY "END", WITH "BOOL:TRUE" INSIDE.

This one take the first begin and searche the first bool:false before search the end. That's not right.
    (?s)(BEGIN.*?BOOL:FALSE.*?END)

What I want its like using a filter on

```
(?s)(BEGIN.*?BOOL\:FALSE.*?END)
```

filter by BOOL:FALSE

```
(?s)(BEGIN.*?BOOL\:FALSE.*?END)[.FILTERBY_BOOL:FALSE
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead for this:

```
BEGIN((?!TRUE).)*?END
```

This checks for every dot that you have whether there's not `TRUE` ahead, until `END`. So, all the other blocks without `TRUE` will be removed.

You can also insert a `[\r\n]?` to make things a little cleaner:

```
[\r\n]?BEGIN((?!TRUE).)*?END
```

[Updated the regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eR5gB0).

EDIT:
If you want to only pinpoint `FALSE`, you can use this regex, which is a bit longer:

```
[\r\n]?BEGIN(?:(?!FALSE|END).)*?FALSE(?:(?!FALSE|END).)*?END
```

[Updated regex101 with this one](http://regex101.com/r/rF0oI6).

Comment: I think this is a beautiful solution, +1 for that Jerry.